# There's any plans on switching to a new package manager (like dnf or pacman)?

Tags: apt, package-management

I was a very devoted Elementary OS user (I used Elementary 0.2 for more than a year and a half) but in the last year I've moved to Fedora 20 for stability reasons. Elementary OS is an awesome OS, but I need a more stable OS because I work with Big Data and Machine Learning.

I really liked the `dnf` package manager (from Fedora, CentOS, etc.) and I also loved the `pacman` (Arch Linux) package manager. I know that `apt` is derived from Ubuntu, but there's any plans on switching to a new package manager in the near future?

`apt` is awnkward, ugly and everything crashes with it. Elementary OS is the Linux distribution of the future (at least for the end-user), this great system don't deserves `apt`. It deserves something better, faster and prettier than apt.

Any plans on that?

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with apt.It is very good and has a lot of software

Comment: Have you ever used DNF or Pacman? If not, please use them for some weeks and you'll see the difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not any plans to switch away from Debian/apt at this time

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu itself is apparently working on [replacing Deb packages with Snappy apps](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2942267/why-ubuntu-plans-to-replace-traditional-linux-packages-with-something-better.html), and GNOME is working on cross-distro [sandboxed applications](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/SandboxedApps).

I wouldn't be surprised if one of these projects made it into Ubuntu LTS, which could get rolled into Elementary. To be clear, that's *100% speculation* on my part. That said, folks from upstream projects definitely are working on new packaging tools.